# Как получить свойства точки при клике. Yandex map api

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Нужно при нажатии на объект(точку) получить ее свойство. Пытаюсь сделать так:

```
        //Получаем данные при клике на объект
        myMap.events.add('click', function (e){  
            var placemark = e.get('target');  
            var id = placemark.properties.get('id'); 
            // Получаем данные для запроса из свойств метки.  
            console.log(id);
        });
```

Но почему то не срабатывает даже событие клика. В чем может быть загвоздка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы подписываетесь на событие клик по карте, а кликаете по метке. При клике по метке событие клика на карте не сработает. Решение: подписывайтесь на клик по метке https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/geo_object_collection

Comment: а что если я из json Добавляю метки, как мне быть?

Comment: добавьте в коллекцию, как в примере, который я скинул выше.

Comment: да уже решил, у меня там просто был объект geoQueryResult, на него и навесил, спасибо )

Answer (score 0):

zoinx2012
а если метки сформированы так:

window.myObjects = ymaps.geoQuery({
type: "FeatureCollection",
features: [
{
type: 'Feature', id: 0,
properties: {
balloonContentHeader:

...

Как быть?

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).